# Error in Other IIS sites, Due to after hosting Python Web application in IIS

Tags: python, iis, flask, wfastcgi

I have deployed Python Webservice using Flask and fastcgi in IIS server,

https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8

It works fine with 8080 port [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hWPn.png)

But Other existing IIS applications are stopped wotking its throws following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUfc2.png)

So Kindly help me to fix the issue.

Note : I am new to Python.

Comment: Is your issue solved?If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the fast CGI environment variable which you set as below:

[image]

now select your site and then double click on the application setting.

click add from the action pane.

[image]

Set the PYTHONPATH variable(which is your site folder path):

[image]

And the WSGI_HANDLER (my Flask app is named app.py so the value is app.app — if yours is named site.py it would be site.app or similar):

[image]

Click OK and browse to your site.